# Trying to get this VBA in Excel to open a specific folder to select excel files to merge, I seem to be going round in circles as usual

Tags: vba, select, directory

Trying to get this VBA in Excel to open a specific folder to select excel files to merge, I seem to be going round in circles as usual.....

```
Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    
    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
    
    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWorkSheet
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to modify the code to use a specific path for a folder would be much appreciated.

Here's hoping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub mergeFilesBis()
    'Define variables:
    Dim i As Integer, tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook, tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim initialFolder As String
    
    initialFolder = "C:\"
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    With tempFileDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = initialFolder
        If Not .Show = -1 Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.count

        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i))
        
        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy After:=mainWorkbook.sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.count)
        Next tempWorkSheet
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but it still results in the Browse window opening at the last opened folder rather than the specific folder I want the window to show.

Comment: @Eric the Viking: But where in your code do you try setting an initial folder to be open? Can you better explain (in words) which is your problem, in fact? Do you need the Dialog to open in a specific folder? If yes, in which one? VBA is not able to read your mind... It was supposing that you will browse to find the appropriate folder.

Comment: Just to make sure my question is clear, what I am doing is importing a series of individual workbooks to a main workbook.  The individual workbooks have been exported from access to a specific folder which also contains the main workbook.  What I want the VBA to do is always open the folder with the exported files in it, rather than going to the last folder openend and expecting the user to then navigate to the correct folder.

Comment: I appreciate I haven't told VBA to go to this specific folder, what I am after is the correct code to tell it to if you see what I mean.

Comment: @Eric the Viking: I adapted the code to open the dialog in a specific folder. **But you must 'tell' to the code which is this folder path**, correctly filling the variable `initialFolder`. Be rure that the folder path ends in "\". Please test the code and send some feedback.

Comment: FaneDuru, many thanks my problem seems to have been solved by your adapted code.  Big thumbs up, I live and learn!

Comment: @Eric the Viking: Glad I could help! But, we here in such a case, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...